# Как получить количество найденных комментариев в поиске вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот таким образом я вывожу текст самих комментариев:

```php
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->comment_content;
}
```

А как вывести именно количество найденных коментариев?

Это сам поиск:
`<?php $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query( [ 'search' => get_search_query() ] ); $comments = $comments_query->comments; ?>`

Это вывод найденных комментариев:
`<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) {   echo $comment->comment_content;} ?>`

А надо не просто текст самого коммента а еще и автора кто этот коммент оставил и ссылку на запись к которой относится этот комент?

Comment: А вот `$comments` у вас - это массив комментариев? если да, то как-то так - `count($comments)`.

Comment: Супер Спасибо! получилось! только теперь вопрос следующий когда вывожу список найденных коменнтариев, тобишь текст то надо еще и сделать ссылку на автора этогго коментария и запись к которой люди оставили коммент? подскажите как это сделать

Comment: Ну так сделайте `var_dump($comment)` и посмотрите что там внутри.

Comment: Как сделать var_dump($comment)?

Comment: [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 0):

Если `$comments` - это массив, то длину можно получить вот так - `count($comments)`.