# Как в результатах поиска вывести автора и запись найденого комментария (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Это сам поиск:
`<?php $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query( [ 'search' => get_search_query() ] ); $comments = $comments_query->comments; ?>`

Это вывод найденных комментариев:
`<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) {   echo $comment->comment_content;} ?>`

А надо не просто текст самого коммента а еще и автора кто этот коммент оставил и ссылку на запись к которой относится этот комент?

Comment: Вы уже точно такой же вопрос задавали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1550046/532877